# Floated spans in IE7 forces parent div to expand to 100% available width

Tags: css, internet-explorer-7, css-float

I browsed similar questions here in Stack Overflow, but none of them solves the problem:

http://jsfiddle.net/2SGCb/12/

I have too spans:

```
<span class="in_bl right">Right</span>
<span class="in_bl left">Left</span>
```

I need to display them in the reverse order, that is why I am floating them.
This works well in all browsers except Internet explorer.

Please take a look at this fiddle in IE: http://jsfiddle.net/2SGCb/12/

Actually there are two problems:

a) word "Right" is floated to the very end of the window

b) both words "Left" and "Right" now appears in the second row, not in the first.

In html code 'Right' must go before 'Left' (so strip_tags() should result in "Right Left") but user must see "Left Right".
Any other suggestions how to swap visually (but not in html code) too spans are welcome.

Comment: can you share an example as to what exactly is needed, may be sample of expected output?

Comment: [http://jsfiddle.net/2SGCb/12/](http://jsfiddle.net/2SGCb/12/) - this looks ok in Chrome/FF/Opera but not in IE. So expected output is  [http://jsfiddle.net/2SGCb/12/](http://jsfiddle.net/2SGCb/12/) to look the same in IE as in the other browsers.

Answer (score 0):

> a) word "Right" is floated to the very end of the window

Instead of floating one element to the left and the other to the right, float both of them left. Then create the HTML structure to suit your layout needs. [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/2SGCb/16/)

For example, I swapped these and floated them left:

```
<span class="in_bl left">Left</span>
<span class="in_bl right">Right</span>
```

> b) both words "Left" and "Right" now appears in the second row, not in the first.

Using `display: inline-block` in IE7 you must include `*display:inline` *and* `zoom:1` in order to trigger 'hasLayout' and make it work.

Comment: I forgot to mention that in html code 'Right' must go before 'Left' (so strip_tags() should result in "Right Left") but user must see "Left Right".